# Unable to Transpile Specific Third-Party node_modules Scripts Using Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, babeljs, webpacker

I'm working with a Rails application, using Webpacker to bundle assets. I'm using a particular library I've installed via `yarn` whose code needs to be transpiled in my project. I'm trying to do this by modifying the paths that are ignored by Webpack/babel-loader within my `config/webpack/environment.js` file.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

// Ignore all node_modules packages EXCEPT `a-random-third-party-package`:
babelLoader.exclude = /node_modules\/(?!(a-random-third-party-package))/;

module.exports = environment;
```

This is NOT working, though. For example, the JavaScript classes and static properties that exist in the third party package aren't transpiled at all in my bundle. But when I copy that same code into my own JS files, it's transpiled as expected.

How can I get this package to transpile like I want?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I had been using `yarn link` to work with this package separately and test it within this Rails application. For whatever reason, this was interfering with the build step, preventing it from being properly transpiled.

If you run into this yourself, verify that none of your dependencies are `yarn link`-ed, and if they are, run `yarn unlink` so you can locally test Webpacker without issues.